# Are we one of the top 3 awesomest stack exchange sites, with a 100% answer rate?

Tags: discussion

Let's say, theoretically, Joel Spolsky wrote a blog entry about Stack Exchange, and proudly exclaimed that three of the SE sites have a 100% answer rate. Are we one of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfection is a journey, not a destination

100% today is not 100% tomorrow, so let's keep it up and not rest on our laurels.

Answer (score 3):

I also recommend

http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true

If you want to compare your site's stats with other sites in the Stack Exchange network.

Use the "Sort by:" drop-down to change the ranking orders.

Of course, we love all of our virtual children equally.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Yes we are.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/state-of-the-stack-2010-a-message-from-your-ceo/

[image]

Go us!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no, we do not have a 100% answer rate: **[there are currently 3 questions with no answer at all](https://photo.stackexchange.com/unanswered)**.

(Close indeed - 99.8% answer rate - but no cigar.)

Comment: Presumably we did when Joel made the chart. :)

Comment: Anyway, one of those is a duplicate, one is a borderline-off-topic specific-camera-recommendation question, and the third is recently asked and is kind of... boring. For the first two, vote to close.

Comment: I don't think we were; currently there's two unanswered and they both predate the blog post by at least a week. Cooking, I'd buy - they have just one unanswered question asked yesterday; English probably not though - just one unanswered question, but asked six days before the post.

Comment: Also, I agree on closing the two remaining unanswered and voted to do so.

Comment: Both the unanswered questions have not been upvoted, so may have been excluded from the calculations.